# Defining Label on a Model

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way of defining a label for the field on Django Models? My problem(I'm announcing that I'm a Python Beginner, and also a English beginner): I have this field

```
source = models.ForeignKey('Objects',name="Object Source",null=True,blank=True,related_name="Src")
```

So when I execute manage.py migrate, it creats a column on Postgres with ObjectSource name(according to field 'name'). I would like that the name on my database stays 'Source' and the name on my form stays 'Object Source'.

I could just change on my forms file, but on my forms I simply have:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = MyTable
```

If there's a way of defining this on model, would save me a lot of work, cause then I wouldn't have to define each line on my forms.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) parameter to the field.